# Check if activity is in tasks activity stack

Tags: android, android-actionbar

So in my application i got 2 activities A and B with A as parent activity of B.
This way i am able to go from B to A by clicking the home (left top) actionbar button.
Activity B opens if i click a button in A. So thats one case how to reach B.

The other one is via a notification-click which only occurres if the app is closed. Therefor activity A is not in the task stack when the actionbar home button is clicked.
So my question is how to :
1. check if the activity A is in stack and create it manually
or
2. force activity A to create if i click the actionbar-home in B

already searched alot but didnt find a solution yet.
Hope you got one ! :)

Comment: You can open activity A on notification click which then calls Activity B. This way you have both activities in the stack and back press won't cause a problem.

Comment: hm yea thats probably what im ending up using. works fine :) ty